# QMediaPlayer и прослушивание музыки из Сети

Tags: qtcreator, qt, c++

Всем доброго времени суток!

Суть проблемы такова:
Объекту QMediaPlayer дается ссылка, по которой находится аудиозапись, устанавливается громкость и начинаеться воспроизведение. Есть сигнал (bufferStatusChanged), который возвращает статус буфера, т.е. если буфер заполнен (100%) - играем, если нет, то ждем до того, пока он заполнится, и только тогда начинаем или продолжаем играть (сигнал возращает от 0 до 100, когда загружено количество, достаточное для воспроизверение нескольких секунд, и замолкает при том, что кеширование продолжается).

Как сделать так, чтобы в процессе воспроизведения я мог получать данные о том, сколько процентов или какое количество данных из данной аудиозаписи уже попало в буфер. К примеру, когда в вк слушаете музыку или смотрите видео, всегда бежит полоска, которая показывает, сколько из данной записи уже закешено.

Answer (score 1):

Тут, похоже, только если попробовать получать данные из `QIODevice`. У `QMediaPlayer` имеется метод `mediaStream()`, который предоставит доступ к объекту `QIODevice`. У последнего имеется сигнал `readyRead()`, подключив который можно получать размер доступных для чтения данных посредством `QIODevice::bytesAvailable()`.